# Strange Windows 8.1 Boot load time

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

So this started all of a sudden. I'm not sure exactly when but a few days ago. Basically i am running Windows 8.1 on a Samsung 850 SSD. Nothings wrong with it, but suddenly after it gets into windows, there's a reallllly slow patch where no applications will open and for a good 1 minute the computer will be in a sort of stasis.

The icons on boot up for all my files are white and I have to manually hit refresh for them to load.

The sequence is thus:

- Boots up really fast coz SSD
- Hard drive monitor comes online immediately
- Long pause where even if I click on outlook or itunes or steam, application gets stalled and takes forever to launch
- Till it sort of snaps out of it and Nod32, managers and the other stuff comes online.
- I have to hit refresh for my icons to go back to normal from being completely white.

I have tried disabling a bunch of stuff in msconfig and its pretty light, but I don't understand this pause that happens.

Any ideas?

*Update*: 
Hardware

i7 5820k

Reference Zotac GTX 980Ti with a modded bios(EVGA SC)

16GB 2400 DDR4 RAM

Samsung 850 512Gb SSD, 3 TB Red, 1 TB Green

Don't think its the modded BIOS because i did that before and it was running fine after it was flashed and overclocked.

Comment: [Similar problem](http://superuser.com/q/928160/194694) 5 weeks ago, and I also have a system that has identical symptoms. What's your hardware? Maybe there's a faulty driver that causes this.

Comment: Added my hardware

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting one...  You say that you have disabled a load of things in msconfig, have you tried disabling everything in the startup section & re-enabling each one at a time (I know this is a bit laborious, but this could identify if an application is at fault in the first instance, otherwise it could be a service that is at fault & the same process would be needed).<br />
Another alternative would be, within msconfig, there is an option for Diagnostic Startup, try using that & see what difference that makes?

Comment: Another thing to check, does Windows register the full 16GB of RAM that you have installed, I'm wondering if maybe it could be a faulty RAM module or Motherboard socket, so you may think you're utilising the full 16GB but actually getting less.

Comment: Check the smart diagnostics for your disk. [HDDScan – free HDD diagnostic utility](http://hddscan.com/)

Comment: My system shows the full 16 gigs in use. This is a screenshot of what i have enabled. http://i.imgur.com/HdMfWkZ.png

Comment: Have you tried disabling Nod32? I find that anti-malware software can introduce rather hefty startup delays, often without any obvious clues as to what's going on. You might have to uninstall Nod32 to know for sure. Anti-malware typically inserts itself into the startup process early and can be fairly I/O intensive initially, which can make a Windows system seems stalled.

Comment: So after a long time of trial and error, basically it was intel rapid storage technology that had a "delayed launcher", it was actually called that. Disabling it returns my boot up process to its original timings.

Answer (score 0):

Was a startup item called "Delayed Launcher" run by Intel rapid storage technology. After i disabled that, my boot up times went back to normal. Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your task manager to see what keeps your CPU high. Use process explorer if more detail is needed.
- End the task that keeps the high load and then configure the system so it will not load it at start-up
- If it is svchost, you may have a virus or a memory leak, in which case

  - update the OS and let it patch
  - update the AV and do a complete scan

Also, specifically check what nod32 does, it may perform a scan right at start-up.